# Prevent a window from becoming active in Electron

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

### What I want to do

I am creating an on-screen keyboard for windows10.
(The string to be input is obtained by js code, so I am creating a GUI in electron.)
(There is no particular meaning to being an electron.)

The on-screen keyboard here is to input text into the another active window.
It is not to input text into a text box in the keyboard's window itself.
For example, if you click a key on the keyboard when Notepad is the active window, text is entered into Notepad.

Therefore, even if a key in the keyboard is clicked, the original window must remain active.

### What I did

I added [`focusable: false`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#:%7E:text=focusable%20boolean%20(optional)%20%2D%20Whether%20the%20window%20can%20be%20focused.%20Default%20is%20true.%20On%20Windows%20setting%20focusable%3A%20false%20also%20implies%20setting%20skipTaskbar%3A%20true.%20On%20Linux%20setting%20focusable%3A%20false%20makes%20the%20window%20stop%20interacting%20with%20wm%2C%20so%20the%20window%20will%20always%20stay%20on%20top%20in%20all%20workspaces.) to `BrowserWindow` constructor.

```js
// https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start#recap

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },

    focusable: false,
    // alwaysOnTop: true,
    // resizable: true,
    // movable: true,
});
```

### The problem

When I start with the above options, the window become not active.
However, the title bar and menu bar are not available.
Therefore, I cannot move, resize, maximize, minimize, or close the window.

How can I make it so that clicking on content does not switch the active window, while still being able to operate the title bar, etc.?